# strtotime in jQuery with generic dates

Tags: jquery, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to convert a date like "16/8/2015" (d/m/Y) to a unix timestamp.
All i'm finding are codes for converting dates like "18-Jun-2015" with:

```
Date.parse("18-Jun-2015")
```

Which works, but that's not what I need.
Any leads on converting other types of date formats?

Comment: If that works, but isn't what you need, then what do you need?

Comment: I need to convert a date like "18/6/2015", not one with text (e,g 18-Jun-2015)

Comment: A date string separated by `/` must be in US format for the Date() object to parse it - eg. `m/d/Y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var date = new Date('2015-08-16');
```